# Как создать index столбцу в sqlite таблице

Tags: android, android-sqlite, index

Требуется создать `index` для определенного столбца, к примеру, к столбцу `name`.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE book (" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "name TEXT ," +
        "autor TEXT" +
        ");");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` столбцу в `sqlite` таблице можно создать так.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE book (" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "name TEXT ," +
        "autor TEXT" +
        ");");



db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX bookIndex1 ON book (name);");
```